# With Google Analytics API how can I get the page views between the start and end date?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I am able to get the page views of the days between start day and the end day. But is it possible to split it into the different days?

I am trying to get all the page views of each day within two months. What is the best way to go about it without needing to send a request for each day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the dimension of date:

[Query Explorer Link Date Example](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253Adate&metrics=ga%253Apageviews&start-date=2014-01-04&end-date=2014-02-18&max-results=50)

[Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)